# Spinner with different view for each item

Tags: android, spinner

I try to make a Spinner where the first item in the dropdownview has no radio button. I override the viewtypes of the arrayadapter to make sure there are two different views in the spinner and the views don't get recycled for the wrong item. Then I override getDropDownView of the arrayadapter to remove the radio button from the first item. This is working, but the selected item doesn't show the radio button. I think I wouldn't have to setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio), because it should always be there, but this is not the case. Any Ideas? Thank you!

```
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount()
        {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)
        {
            if (position == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (position == 0)
            {
                View vw = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) vw;
                if (tv != null)
                {
                    tv.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    return tv;
                }
                return vw;
            } else
            { 
                View vw = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) vw;
                if (tv != null)
                {
                    tv.setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    return tv;
                }
                return vw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. And YES, as **pzagor2** said - Spinner doesn't support multi layout recycling for dropdown list (getDropDownView). It just doesn't call getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType. Here is an issue - [#17128](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128).

But it still call these methods for getView which is used to display current spinner item and detect spinner width.

**Workaround:** You can just check if supplied convertView has correct type and don't use it if it's not true. It will help in some cases, for example, when you have two types and one type is used less frequently than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount are not getting called when using ArrayAdapter with Spinner. One solution is to not recycle convertView and assume that it's always null. But you get a laggy spinner and a lots of GC calls in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that view recycling doesn't work for Spinner, don't use Spinner if you have multiple views.  Instead use a TextView styled as a Spinner and in onClick opens your custom dialog showing the dropdown.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/labels_spinner"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>


@OnClick(R.id.labels_spinner)
public void onSpinnerClick(View view) {
    // Open dropdown dialog
}
```